# Angular-schema-form does not show

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm testing the angular-schema-form with the addon of datepicker however it does not seem to display properly can anybody please assist me to
https://github.com/ejayimperial/schema-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by removing the decorator on the main.html

```
sf-decorator="{{decorator}}"
```